# Integration of product of fraction function and greatest integer function

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve $\int_0^{20}  ${x}.[x] dx. I know how to integrate [x] but am confused with this product.

Can I substitute ${x} = x - [x]$?

Comment: Seems like a good way to attempt it.  Have you tried it?

Comment: My attempt is split this in 20 parts, 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc,  first one will be $\int_0^1 x.(0)$ second one will be $\int_1^2 x(1)$ etc.,

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the fraction function for $x  \geq 0$ is indeed,

$$\{x\}=x - [x]$$

So we have,

$$\int_{0}^{20} [x] \{x \}dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{20} [x](x-[x]) dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{20} x[x] dx -\int_{0}^{20} [x]^2 dx$$

Partition $[0,20)$ into $\bigcup_{n=0}^{19} [n,n+1)$. For every $x \in [n,n+1)$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $[x]=n$. This gives,

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{19} \int_{n}^{n+1} xn dx -\sum_{n=0}^{19} \int_{n}^{n+1} n^2 dx $$

$$=2565-2470$$

$$=95$$